# Not using the else

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm try to not use the `else` in the code and just the `if`. But when I run it and enter "Q" it say error of converting in the `total += Convert.ToInt32(input);`. Is there a way around this?

```
do
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number or Q to quit", input);
    input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (input.ToUpper() == "Q")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    else
    {
        total += Convert.ToInt32(input);
        numbersEntered++;
        average = ((double)total / numbersEntered);
        Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}\t Numbers Entered: {1}\t Average: {2}\t", total, numbersEntered, average);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

while (input.ToUpper() != "Q");
```

Comment: You sample shows reasonable usage of `else`. There is no way from given code to figure out how you incorrectly converted `else` branch into `if` with reverse condition. Please update sample... And if possible add good reason (like "my assignment requires...") of avoiding `else`.

Comment: What is the value of input when you reach the if statement? Seems likely that it is in fact not just "Q".

Comment: I've run this in a new console application and it does function correctly and quit as expected when `Q` or `q` is entered.

Comment: It works fine for me. Don't forget that you're asking for a keypress between inputs...

Comment: if Q is for quit, then just add a break/return/exit (whichever is appropriate to how this code is being called) inside the if block.  Then you don't need the else, because the only way for the program to continue would be if the user didn't enter "Q"

Comment: Wrap the if and else in a try catch this would be an extremely dirty workaround.

Comment: `it say error` And the error is??

Comment: You can (and should) use a `.TryParse` or some other method of input verification, what if the user puts in "R", or "S", or "G"?

Comment: Step through and see what the input really is

Comment: @tnw: " it say error of converting in the `total += Convert.ToInt32(input);`" which suggests to me that it isn't able to convert input to an int. The OP might not have quoted the exception but he did say what the error was.

Comment: thanks the break work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `break;` to stop the loop so you don't need the `else`.

```
do{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number or Q to quit", input);
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input.ToUpper() == "Q"){
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
        break;
    }
    total += Convert.ToInt32(input);
    numbersEntered++;
    average = ((double)total / numbersEntered);
    Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}\t Numbers Entered: {1}\t Average: {2}\t", total, numbersEntered, average);
    Console.ReadKey();
} while (input.ToUpper() != "Q");
```

Comment: This will throw an exception though if the input is any other non-integer character than `Q`.

Comment: @davidsbro Correct, it will. I was simply answering the question he had about the else statement.

Comment: Ok. I was just wondering why you hadn't addressed that potential problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use TryParse to test if the input is a numeric. Here's an example for int (you'll need to define the out variable yourself).

```
else if (Int32.TryParse(input,out inputVal) {
```